# Merging half related data into the same class?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, solid-principles

I have data that represents a button. These data are composed of elements like id (string), text (string), position on screen (numeric values), image url (string), size (numeric value). It also has some domain-related data. At first, I wanted to create two classes, the first one having all the non graphical data, the second one having all the graphical data (so I would avoid mixing unrelated kind of data). But then, I find myself with two classes.

Should I leave things like that, or should I merge them, so my life is easier (but then, it would not be very compliant to the Single Responsability Rule...) ?

Comment: Domain data goes to domain classes, UI data goes to UI classes. There is no conflict, but in your mind. Think it again. ;-)

Comment: Why would a button have domain-related data in the first place ? ...

Comment: Why would your life be easier by having one class with, let's say, 500 lines of code, versus having two classes of 250 lines of code? Multiple classes bring clarity & reuse rather than complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact, a very common practice. They are called `ViewModels`, and they are exactly for what you're using them for - view specific state.

To help ease conversion, there are libraries like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) that can automatically map between a ViewModel and a Domain Model. This saves you wiring it all up yourself and writing even more boilerplate code.

TLDR: It's common to have the two classes. Don't stress about it.

Comment: I would suggest measuring the performance of AutoMapper for your scenario. For a recent project I found it added considerable overhead.